# How to use selectize.js in laravel for tagging?

Tags: laravel, tagging, selectize.js

I can use selectize js for my laravel framework project tagging posts?
I use for tagging many to many relation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but I prefer select2 if you gonna use multi-select it's easier to get it as an array from the request directly

https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox

I hope it's helpful